# How to has role in another guild and give rank in new guild Discord.js v.12

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
run: async (client, message, args) => {
    let rolemember = message.guild.roles.cache.get("846761815899111460");
    const supportGuild = message.client.guilds.cache.get('830488981518942319')
    console.log(`supportGuild : ${supportGuild}`)
    const usermember = supportGuild.members.cache.get(message.author.id)
    console.log(`usermember : ${usermember}`)

    if(usermember.roles.has("831476829126393887")) {
      message.member.roles.add(rolemember);
      console.error();
      return message.channel.send(`${message.author} You already have this role`);
    }
    else{
      return message.channel.send(`${message.author} You don't have this role!`);
    }
  }
}
```

In the log it says `usermember : undefined`

And the error is:

> (node:3696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Thanks Zsolt Meszaros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) the user instead of relying on the cache, and check if the user exists in the other guild:

```js
run: async (client, message, args) => {
  const rolemember = message.guild.roles.cache.get('846761815899111460');
  const supportGuild = message.client.guilds.cache.get('830488981518942319');
  const usermember = await supportGuild.members.fetch(message.author.id);

  if (!usermember)
    return message.channel.send(`${message.author} is not found on the ${supportGuild.name} server`);

  if (!usermember.roles.cache.has('831476829126393887'))
    return message.channel.send(`${message.author} You don't have this role!`);

  message.member.roles.add(rolemember);
  return message.channel.send(`${message.author} You already have this role`);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

**Main Issue:** the `.has()`function is not a function inside the [#GuildMemberRoleManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager) Class.

Try:

```
usermember.roles.cache.get("831476829126393887")
```

Inside the if statement

Also you didn't point out which line was giving the error so I'm assuming the user is where the issue is. Be more clear next time.

Comment: it say again

usermember : undefined
(node:16652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
    at Object.run (C:\Users\###\###\###\##\commands\rank.js:15:19)

Comment: Why dont you try this for `usermember`: `const usermember = message.author`